# ib_insync: Complete list of all sprinters on the DAX

Tags: ib-insync

I need a way to dynamically establish a list of Contract objects containing each an ING Sprinter on the DAX index, both long and short, in Python using ib_insync. I have no idea how to proceed. Initializing the TWS, connecting to it and so on is not the issue. I have written a Python script for trading in stocks using ib_insync. However, I can not dynamically obtain a list of sprinters. How is this done? There must be an API function I can't find. If there is an issue with sprinters, then a similar list of turbos or speeders would be fine too.